# Getting 400 from samltest.id when attempting SP-initiated worflow

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have used itfoxtec's SAML2 library to implement an SP in my ASP.NET MVC app. I am testing using samltest.id as the IdP. The IdP-initiated workflow works perfectly, but the SP-initiated workflow always gets a 400 error back from samltest.id. I have attempted to look through samltest.id's log to see if an error is being recorded there for my request, but I cannot seem to find anything there.

This is the Action that handles the URL that he user would go to when initiating SSO:

```
public ActionResult SSOLogin() {
    LogManager logger = new LogManager("SSOLogin");

    string hostname = this.GetHostname();
    SchoolSettings settings = this.GetClientSettings();

    if (settings.UseSAMLSSO) {
        Saml2Configuration samlConfig = null;
        try {
            samlConfig = SamlConfigLoader.GetSaml2Config(HttpContext, settings, this.IsSandbox());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.exception($"loading Saml2Configuration for {hostname}", e);
        }

        if (samlConfig != null) {
            try {
                var binding = new Saml2RedirectBinding();

                binding.SetRelayStateQuery(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Home/Index", Url.Content("~/") } });

                return binding.Bind(new Saml2AuthnRequest(samlConfig) {

                }).ToActionResult();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error($"Exception redirecting to IdP. {e.GetType().ToString()}: {e.Message}\n{e.StackTrace}");
                ViewBag.ssoerror = $"Error redirecting to IdP for {hostname}";
            }
        } else {
            logger.critical($"Could not load SAML2 configuration for {hostname}");
            ViewBag.ssoerror = $"Could not load SAML2 configuration for {hostname}";
        }
    } else {
        ViewBag.ssoerror = "SSO is not configured for this client. Please contact Support";
    }

    return Redirect("/Home/SSOError");
}
```

The method that loads a client-specific metadata looks like this:

```
public static Saml2Configuration GetSaml2Config(HttpContextBase context, SchoolSettings forSchool, bool forSandbox) {
    LogManager log = new LogManager("getSaml2Config");

    Saml2Configuration config = new Saml2Configuration();
    if (!forSandbox) {
        config.Issuer = _saml2Issuer;
    } else {
        config.Issuer = _saml2IssuerSandbox;
    }

    config.SignatureAlgorithm = _saml2SignatureAlgo;
    config.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
    config.RevocationMode = (X509RevocationMode)Enum.Parse(typeof(X509RevocationMode), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Saml2:RevocationMode"]);
    config.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(config.Issuer);

    var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
    if (forSchool.SAMLMetadataLocationIsUrl) {
        try {
            entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(forSchool.SAMLMetadataLocation));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error($"Exception caught loading metadata from school {forSchool.Hostname} at URL {forSchool.SAMLMetadataLocation}\n Exception {e.GetType().ToString()}: {e.Message}\n{e.StackTrace}");
            entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor = null;
        }
    } else {
        var schoolMetadataPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/SAMLMetadata/" + forSchool.SAMLMetadataLocation);
        log.info($"Loading metadata for school {forSchool.Hostname} from file {schoolMetadataPath}");
        try {
            entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromFile(schoolMetadataPath);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error($"IOException caught loading metadata for school {forSchool.Hostname} from file {schoolMetadataPath}: {ioe.Message}\n{ioe.StackTrace}");
            entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error($"Exception caught loading metadata for school {forSchool.Hostname} from file {schoolMetadataPath}\n Exception {e.GetType().ToString()}: {e.Message}\n{e.StackTrace}");
            entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor = null;
        }
    }

    if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null) {
        if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.Count() > 0) {
            config.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
        } else {
            log.error($"WARNING: metadata for {forSchool.Hostname} does not have any SingleSignOnServices that could be parsed.");
        }

        if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleLogoutServices.Count() > 0) {
            config.SingleLogoutDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleLogoutServices.First().Location;
        } else {
            log.error($"WARNING: metadata for {forSchool.Hostname} does not have any SingleLogoutServices that could be parsed.");
        }

        if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates.Count() > 0) {
            config.SignatureValidationCertificates.AddRange(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates);
        } else {
            log.error($"WARNING: metadata for {forSchool.Hostname} does not have any SigningCertificates that could be parsed.");
        }                
    } else {
        throw new Exception("IdPSsoDescriptor not loaded from metadata.");
    }

    return config;
}
```

If it would help to clarify the situation, I can add the code for the AssertionConsumerService Action which works perfectly in an IdP-initiated scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem. It comes down to this line of code in the GetSaml2Config method:

```
config.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
```

This naively takes the first SingleSignOnService element in the metadata and decides that it is the correct one to use, but that was not always the case that this assumption was true. What I really wanted was to get a SingleSignOnService element for and HTTP-POST binding:

```
config.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.Where(s => s.Binding.ToString().IndexOf("HTTP-POST") > 0).FirstOrDefault()?.Location;
```

This works well for all of the cases that I have found since.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.

It is probably an integration issue but very hard to find if the IdP do not log an error message.

What error status message do you get back instead of success, maybe that tells you something.

Maybe the IdP do not accept the SAML 2.0 Authn Response, here is something to look for:

- The config.SingleSignOnDestination probably is required
- Meybe the IdP requere the request to be signed
- It is also possible to add other attributes in the request, do the IdP documentation describe any requirements?